# Where to find the latest chrome driver to use with selenium

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I’m searching for a source or way to find the latest chrome driver in order to make my project work using selenium.

I’ve tried to follow the link presented by visual studio code however the best I can find is 114 however the latest version and current version I have download is 122.0.6261.95

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome version 115 and above, find the link below where you can download the chrome drivers.

[Link to download latest chrome drivers](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/)

Comment: I've found a solution thanks to you , appreciated